# illegal reference to 16-bit data in 'identifier'

Tags: assembly, x86

I was looking at some code and found this instruction:

```
mov ES : [BX], AX
```

It's raising a compiler error:

```
illegal reference to 16-bit data in 'first operand'
```

I've never seen that notation. Can someone explain it to me and how to fix this error?

The code itself is from inline assembly being written in a C program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BX is a 16-bit register, and cannot be used to address data when compiling 32-bit code. You may be able to change the target CPU to x86 and get it to work without changing the code.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zyca2kh.aspx

Comment: The code itself was suppose to work in real address mode. Any idea how I can do that in a C program?

Comment: you need to compile it as a 16 bit program

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is very much depending on a compiler and selected dialect.

At least on NASM correct syntax would be

```
MOV [ES:BX],AX
```

In short, whole memory reference need to be in square brackets. Segment overrides, even though they really are prefixes (e.g. `ES:` compiles to 26h), need to be included in the memory reference.